# Action of simple reflections

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, semisimple-lie-algebras

I have a question regarding the inner product that appears in the study of root systems in Lie theory.

I have not seen anywhere an algorithm that explicitly calculates the product $(\alpha_i^\vee,\beta)$ appearing in the formula
$$s_i(\beta)=\beta-(\alpha_i^\vee,\beta) \alpha_i,$$
when $\beta$ is arbitrary. I know there are some special formulas when $\beta$ is a simple root or a fundamental weight. But, in general, I have not seen any effective method, at least in the resources I have. I saw this example somewhere, which is of type $B$: $s_3(s_2s_1s_3s_2(\varpi_2)) = s_2s_1s_3s_2(\varpi_2) -2 \alpha_3$.

Can anyone explain how this is gotten? Sorry if the question is too elementary!

Comment: Well any root is a integer linear combination of simple roots and the inner product is bilinear so you can just work it out as a sum of those. You can then read what it is for simple roots off the Cartan matrix.

Comment: For fundamental weights all you need is the observation that they are the dual basis to the coroots: $ (\alpha^\check_i , \omega_i) = \delta_{i,j} $ all other weights (of finite representations) are integral linear combinations of these

Comment: I read somewhere that the inner product is just linear in the first spot but not the second. @Callum

Comment: The inner product is bilinear otherwise it is not an inner product. What you are thinking of is the Cartan pairing: $ \langle \alpha,\beta\rangle := 2\frac{(\alpha,\beta)}{(\alpha,\alpha)}$ which is only linear in the second slot. This is related to what you have got, of course, $ \langle \alpha_i,\beta\rangle = (\alpha^\vee_i , \beta) $ but note that replacing $ \alpha_i $ by a linear combination of $ \alpha_j$'s on the left hand side is *not* the same as replacing $ \alpha^\vee_i$ by the same linear combination of $ \alpha^\vee_j$'s on the right.

Comment: @Callum
Let me do an example to make sure I got it: for type $B$, if I want to calculate $s_3(s_2\varpi_2)$:

$$(\alpha_3^\vee,s_2 \varpi_2)=(\alpha_3^\vee, \varpi_2-\alpha_2)=0-C_{23}=1.$$

This means, $s_3(s_2\varpi_2)=s_2 \varpi_2 - \alpha_3$. Is this right?

Comment: Yes that is correct and I have added my calculations in a full answer as a demonstration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have decided that in addition to my comments it might be helpful to just see some of the calculations. Firstly, I assume that we are in $B_n$ for $n\geq 4$ so these are all long roots we are dealing with. Then we can see that with  $i,j \in \{1,2,3\}$ we have $ (\alpha_i^\vee,\alpha_i) = 2$, $(\alpha_i^\vee,\alpha_j) = -1$ for $j = \pm 1$ and $(\alpha_i^\vee,\alpha_j) = 0$ otherwise. Additionally $(\alpha_i^\vee,\varpi_j) = 0$ for $i \neq j$ and $(\alpha_i^\vee,\varpi_i) = 1$. We can read these off a Cartan matrix or note that $(\alpha_i^\vee,\alpha_j)(\alpha_j^\vee,\alpha_i)$ is exactly the number of lines between the $i$ and $j$ nodes on the Dynkin diagram by definition.

So we can then compute the repeated reflections by hand and linearity of $(\cdot,\cdot)$:
$$ s_2(\varpi_2) = \varpi_2 - (\alpha_2^\vee,\varpi_2)\alpha_2= \varpi_2 - \alpha_2$$
$$ s_3s_2(\varpi_2)= \varpi_2 - \alpha_2 - (\alpha_3^\vee,\varpi_2 - \alpha_2)\alpha_3= \varpi_2 - \alpha_2 - \alpha_3$$
$$ s_1s_3s_2(\varpi_2)= \varpi_2 - \alpha_2 - \alpha_3 - \alpha_1$$
$$ s_2s_1s_3s_2(\varpi_2)= \varpi_2 - 2\alpha_2 - \alpha_3 - \alpha_1 $$
$$ s_3s_2s_1s_3s_2(\varpi_2)= \varpi_2 - 2\alpha_2 - \alpha_3 - \alpha_1 $$

Note the last two are the same which contradicts what your example says and implies that $s_2s_1s_3s_2(\varpi_2)$ is in fact orthogonal to $\alpha_3$ so is unmoved by the final $s_3$ reflection. I double checked in LiE that the last two stages are the same so that should be correct.